# Lock a Google Sheet after 00:00

Tags: google-sheets

I have this situation: every working day I have a Google Sheet where me and my staff enter some data. I want at certain date and time my staff to be blocked from editing that Google Sheet, so only the owner will edit it after that date/time.

The date is the name of the Google Sheet.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 5):

You need a combination of [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) and the [protect()-method of the Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()) can be used.

Your can find the full answer in a similar question that has been posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625064/locking-cells-in-google-sheets-at-a-specific-time.

You can apply the same method for all cells instead of particular ones.