# Can anyone help me with the script for locking non empty cells in a Range at specified time?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I use this in a very small business. We sale the aggregates `E Column` and the items(DUST,6MM,10MM,20MM,40MM) and quantity `F Column` are listed (1 ,2 3, 4, 5,6) in drop down. So the Range `E7:F300` are Unprotected, rest all the cells are protected for the users.

The users select the `Item` and `Quantity` in a day and those cells should be **auto protected** to that user and all other users at specific time. Say night around `10:00pm`. It should protect only Non Empty cell but not the entire Range. I am new to this Script,  Can anyone help me out with the script as per my requirement?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome. It is helpful to understand how this requirement is used in your business. May I try to clarify? please correct me if I am wrong. When some aggregate is issued for a customer, the user goes to the next new line in the spreadsheet and selects the type in Column E, and the quantity in Column F. As the day goes on, users record more transactions in rows of Column E&F. You don't want the cells to be protected as the data is entered, you want to wait until the end of the day, say at 10pm. At that time, you want all the non-blank cells in Column E & F to be protected. Is that right?

Comment: Thank You Mr. Ruben for replying me. you have understood my question.Yes the user goes to the next line and select the aggregate and quantity from E and F Column.yes I dont want those selected cells to be protected immediately because if they do wrong selection and they cant correct if that cells locked immediately. So I want all those non-blank cells in Column E & F to be protected at 10:00 pm. I Kept E7:F300 Unprotected. if 1st day if they select from E7:F13 at night those cells should be protected 2nd day if they select E14:F17 at night those cells should be protected.

Comment: This is a fairly common topic that would have come up in your research, as @Rubén asked your to describe.Is there a reason that you have not applied one of the many topics on this the same subect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lock a Google Sheet after 00:00](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90523/lock-a-google-sheet-after-0000)

Comment: HI This will lock even blank cells. I have checked with it                                                
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625064/locking-cells-in-google-sheets-at-a-specific-time .

Comment: The idea would be to define your range as the non-blank cells.

Comment: Yeah I Mentioned the Range from E7 To F300. As Days go on cells will be non Blank cells .For Example. DAY 1 E7 To F10 Day 2 E11 To F13 Day 3 E14 to F20. (Filling range differs depending upon sales)  .those Filled cells should get protected at night but not whole Range.

Comment: FYI: You can use @name syntax anywhere in your comment to reply to a specific user. This will notify that user in their global inbox. There can also be notification through email if you set it up in the preferences found in your profile page.

Comment: I'd suggest that your script should start by "unprotecting" the entire column, then use `getRange(row, column, numRows)` to define the new range to be protected - the new range being all the cells in Column F from row 7 to the last row of content - `getLastRow()` will give you the last row of content.

Comment: @Tedinoz . Thank You for telling about use of @ Symbol before the name. Well if you dont mind will you please write the complete script. I am not good in Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to protect cells containing content in the range E7:G150 on "sheet="CASH SALE" and range I6:L404 on sheet="HOPPER" at 10:00pm each night.

[Locking cells in Google Sheets at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631220/1330560) (by @Punchlinernon on StackOverflow) provides a good basis for your solution. However your scenario is different because the range to be protected is extended each day. One result is that there would be a protected ranges created every night - over time many dozens of protected ranges would be unnecessarily/unproductively created. So the first step is to remove the protected range then protect the entire range of content. The result is a single protected range.

**Functions**

- `lockRanges()`: this is the primary function that should be assigned to the trigger. This contains the data for each of the relevant sheets and passes processing to the sub-routine `locksub()`.
- `locksub(sheetname, row, col, numCol)`: this is the main processing function. Data is passed from `lockranges()`. It relies on a single utility `columnToLetter()` to produce the range to be protected.
- `columnToLetter(column)`: converts a column number to a letter. This is used to define a range.

**Key Points**

- `var sheetname = "Transactions";` - used for the sheet name, but also used for the description of the protected range.
- `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);` - added to ensure that the changes are made to a specific sheet
- `if (protections[i].getDescription() == sheetname) {` - a test to check if there is already a protected range with the target description, if yes, then the range is unprotected.
- `var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();` - this returns the last row containing content and is used to define the protected range.
- `if( row <= lastRow){` - a test to make sure that there is content; if no content then no action taken
- `var range = sheet.getRange(row, col,numrows,numCol);` - the range to be protected; variables are used for every attribute. The Range starts at row 7 of Column E and extending to the last row of content in Column F.
- `var protection = range.protect().setDescription(sheetname);` - protects the range, and assigns the description.

Props - @AdamL for [columnToLetter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231012/1330560)

---

```
function lockRanges() {

  // this sheet carries the data for the ranges to be adusted
  // and passes this for execution to sub routine = logsub
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // data for CASH SALE
  var sheetname = "CASH SALE";
  //cell variables
  var row = 7; // row 7
  var col = 5; // column E
  var numCol = 3; // Column E, F and G
  locksub(sheetname, row, col, numCol);
  Logger.log("finished lockranges")


  // data for HOPPER
  var sheetname = "HOPPER";
  //cell variables
  var row = 6; //row 6
  var col = 9; // column I
  var numCol = 4; // Column I, K, K and L
  locksub(sheetname, row, col, numCol);
  Logger.log("finished lockranges")

  return;

}

function locksub(sheetname, row, col, numCol){

  // subroutine called from lockRanges
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  /*
  a new protected range is run for eavery time the script is run
  so, test for an existing description and delete it
  then run the rest of the script
  the result should be a single protected range
  */
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    Logger.log("DEBUG: protected range = "+protection.getRange().getA1Notation()+", name = "+protection.getDescription());
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      if (protections[i].getDescription() == sheetname) {
        Logger.log("DEBUG: this protection is named "+sheetname)
        protections[i].remove();
      }
    }
  }

  // get the data range
  var celladdress = sheet.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation();
  var colLetter = columnToLetter(col)
  var datarange = celladdress+":"+colLetter;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the datarange is "+datarange)
  var Evals = ss.getRange(datarange).getValues();
  var Elast = Evals.filter(String).length;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Number of rows of content = "+Elast)
  var numrows = Elast;
  if( Elast>=1){
    // define the range
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, col,numrows,numCol);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation())


    // Lock current range
    // Create protection object. Set description, anything you like.
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription(sheetname);

    // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
    // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    protection.addEditor(me)
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  }

  Logger.log("finished locksub")
return;
}

function columnToLetter(column){
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0){
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

Comment: Thank Q @Tedinoz ,I checked with the script . Its Working Fine. here if the user jumps from 16th row to 25th row then the whole empty cells get protected. however user is not permitted to Jump the empty rows. well the script fulfill my need.  How If I need three more Column in the same sheet to be protected. Like you did with E and F and I Need  W X and Y Column to be protected same way.

Comment: @Srinivas Regarding a user jumping empty rows, I find that a sound thrashing works well to modify user habits; the alternative for the script is to loop through the column and apply protection where a cell has a value. BUT as you get more rows of data, you would create hundreds of protected cell ranges versus just a single range by this script - it's up to you. Regarding three more columns: edit the script to do columns E and F (as written, then duplicate the relevant part of the script to do the second range of three rows. Either than, or create a sub-routine for the repetition.

Comment: Thank Q @Tedinoz. The Script is Really Helpful . I Will Use this Script. For my second range of three rows I Will Create another script file and change the var row = 24;
  var col = 5;
  var numCol = 3 ; Column and row . Thanks Once again

Comment: @Srinivas  A few things for the new range: the script still needs to be on a time-driven trigger; you'll want to remove the protection (based on a description??) (maybe create a new variable for the name?) and "col" ought to be 24 (Column X). BTW, if the answer works for you, them you might also consider "[accepting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)" it.

Comment: HI @Tedinoz . Its not working in my file. I checked your script in a new file there its working fine but when it saved in my file its protecting entire Column. How can i send that file to you. Can i send the file link to you ?

Comment: Share your spreadsheet.

Comment: Kindly give me your gmail ID/ I will share the file with the protection permission

Comment: No, thank you.. _Its not working in my file_ What does this mean? Is there an error message, does it not process at all, is the output not what you expected? You did install the Ticker, didn't you? Any uninstalled any other time driven triggers?

Comment: I Did all of my best knowledge but could not succeed in my file.It protects whole range from e7 to g1002.till last row. Where if I try your Script in new blank file its working fine. Ok i will share my file link here .  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U8xHNPJHOhfxIZc_ny0Ar6w40py-Qajx_tYkUoB5nrI/edit?usp=sharing . Hope you will be a editor to work with this file.

Comment: The updated script is quite different, and it contains three functions as described in the answer.Basically you enter your sheet and some range data in `lockranges`, and the sub-routines look after the rest. So `lockranges` is the function to put in the time-driven installable trigger. Your notes also refer to protection of a range "AA6 To AC36" on Hopper but the parameters for this are different to the other two ranges, so you should apply what you have learned here to develop a script for that range. If this answer has been useful, please accept it.

Comment: Hi.@Tedinoz I Was Busy Could Not get back to you.Two Sheets (Hopper and Cash Sale) together its not working properly. I made Separate file for Hopper Sheet, in your given script I removed The "cash sale" script lines and saved the Script and its working really good.For Range AA6 to AC36 I altered according to me . In fact I don't want protection for those cells any more. now i made another file for Cash Sale and script for cash sale removing hopper script lines, even there its working good. Overall its working like a Jam. Thanks a Ton. Will U alter the above script for two different file?

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, Its not working for two Different Sheet in one File. What to be done?Help me out.

Comment: Apologies - I have been without internet for a week. "Its not working for two Different Sheet in one File" - this is not a helpful statement. The code was based on your spreadsheet which contained two sheets (HOPPER and CASH SALE) in a single file. Please explain what is (or is not) happening and share a copy of your spreadsheet that includes your implementation of the answer showing. When deciding whether to share your spreadsheet, be aware that sharing your spreadsheet will unavoidably expose your email address.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz Thank You for your response . I am sharing the google sheet file with you with the note in the cells . Kindly check it . Thank you. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y9ek6oxV5dzW-6xbxXuNcUIKv-1-IDYjr01rDslKzJ8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Srinivas There are four projects attached to that spreadsheet, and the sheet names are not the same as in your question.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz The Script name is "Autolock 3 sheets" The Sheet names are same in the script which i Mentioned in N1 Cell, What I mentioned in O1 Cell is that I have tried with other file but not with the one i sent the link (Script for Autolock)

Comment: @Srinivas This isn't a script writing/debugging service.It seems to me that the answer was successful and that you are now asking a different question. If you founbd this answer useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz Thank You for your Help. I Never Considered as Service but a  HELP from someone unknown Person. I Was asking for modification for the same requirement.Answer was Very Much Successful and very much Useful.for the 2nd Sheet it has not worked. it took same parameter of 1st sheet. Anyways Thank U for your Great HELP. Let me know how or where Should I Consider as Accepting.

Comment: Hi @TEDINOZ I Found The Accept checkmark and clicked on it. THANK Q

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz I have posted a new question in Stack Exchange, see if u can help me out.The question is   "I Need a script or a formula to get Logged User Name in Column  C  When he enter the cell from drop down list Selection in Column D In Google Sheet" Thank You